# Summing up Qty when RID meets the same rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have try couples of selection but I failed to get the exact answered I want to show. I wish to get ideas from here. Below is the last temp after I selected into.

| RID | LOTID | SAVID | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1278 | G926 |  | 87 |
| A1278.1 | Y976 | D958-G | 108 |
| A1278 | T898 |  | 9 |
| A1278.1 | K892 | D958-G | 32 |
| A1278.2 | B647 | D958-G | 47 |
| A1278.2 | H928 | D958-G | 89 |

What I want the output to be showed as below:

| RID | LOTID | SAVID | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1278.1 | Y976,K892 | D958-G | 140 |
| A1278.2 | B647,H928 | D958-G | 136 |

From the above output, I want to get the sum of `qty` when `RID` is same row and only calculate for those have `SAVID` and `SAVID` must meet the same for each `RID` so that they only can sum up. As you can see, since only the `LOTID` is uniquely, so it hardly make `qty` to be sum up when `RID` meet the same rows.

My question: is there any best way to query the above select statement?

The result is I want to select all with the sum of `qty` and list all `LOTID` as in the result table shown above.

Thanks!

Comment: Cnt you post your "failed" queries?

Comment: What happened to the rows of `A1278`?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this -

```
SELECT rid,  lotid = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + lotid 
              FROM data_table t1
              WHERE t1.rid = t2.rid
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') 
             ,t2.savid
             ,sum(t2.qty ) AS qty
FROM data_table t2
WHERE t2.savid <> ''
GROUP BY rid,t2.savid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `STRING_AGG` along with normal aggregation in newer versions of SQL Server

```sql
SELECT
  t.RID,
  LOTID = STRING_AGG(t.LOTID, ','),
  t.SAVID,
  QTY = SUM(t.QTY)
FROM data_table t
WHERE t.SAVID <> ''
GROUP BY
  t.RID,
  t.SAVID;
```